# Query Returning Blank Table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to run this query Oracle 11g

```
SELECT NAME, TEXT 
FROM DBA_SOURCE 
WHERE NAME in (SELECT LIMIT 
               FROM DBA_PROFILES 
               WHERE RESOURCE_NAME ='PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION') 
ORDER BY NAME, LINE;
```

[image: Talbe with no records]

But it is giving me a blank table with headers "Name" and "Text", with no records.

When I try just:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SYS.DBA_PROFILES;
```

I have a field called "Resource_name" with records about "Password_Verify_Function", my question is why the first query doesn't giving me these records?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the column that contains data such as PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION and PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME? Also, this looks strange to me ` NAME in (SELECT LIMIT`. i.e. Name in LIMIT?

Comment: The name of the column that contains data such as "Password_Verify_Function" is "RESOURCE_NAME", "Limit" is another column of this table, sorry for this, I will edit the question with a entire print screen.

Answer (score 1):

The query compares incompatible items.

The `*_source` views list the code contained in PL/SQL objects.

Profiles are SQL objects. And the limits are the boundaries for each resource.

So the fact your query returns no rows is expected!

Comment: So there is no way to lookup the "password verify function" from "Names" in DBA_SOURCE?

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to find?

Comment: I'm trying to find a list for password testing, I need a table with these parameters for verify password strenght